# change the alert error position 

Tags: html, css, forms, position

Build a form Contact us by EMAIL me form I uploaded it to my server, and I want to change the CSS file the error location (when you click on the submit button, then all fields not filled properly marked an error - red) My question is simple: How do I can change the CSS file so that the error diaphragm on the left and not on the right? Thank you!

The form is in this link: http://lawb.co.il/HTMLPage.html

the CSS file is in this link: http://lawb.co.il/contact_us.css

You can see example for what I want here: [image]
insted of this
[image: enter code here]

Is is possible?

Answer (score 2):

Add `promptPosition:"topLeft"` in contact.js:

```
EMF_jQuery("#emf-form").validationEngine({
                validationEventTriggers:"blur",
                scroll:true,
                promptPosition: "topLeft"
        });
```

And these lines in CSS:

```
   .formError {
   ...
   left: 360px !important;
   ...
   }

   .formError .formErrorContent {
   ...
   width: 310px !important;
   ...
   }

   formError .formErrorArrow {
   ...
   left: 70%;
   ...
   }
```

It should work.

Comment: thank you! It is work..But only partially

If you clik on the again link you can see I changed the script code, from what you said, but still ... The text itself does not move to the left, how can I move the text only, to the left?

Comment: Which text do you refer to?
If you mean the label text, then use this:
`#emf-container li label.emf-label-desc {
font-weight: bold;
padding-right: 2px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}`

Comment: I mean to the text in the red alrt, I want that the alert will be in the Left side..

Comment: Try to add `text-align: left;` to the CSS rule **.formError .formErrorContent**

Comment: thank you! I upload an example, I mean to what that there is in the example, can you tell me how can I fix it?

Comment: I uploaded an example, can you Fix it so waht that there is in the image will be in the CSS or JS code?

Comment: thank you a lot!! you realy helps me! just one more quastion: I uploaded the fixed form (you can see it) thare is an option that all the error messages will be streight to the right side (insted to the left)? that all the messeges will be in Vertically Solid and straight line to the right(now it is to the left)? hope you understand me..

Comment: Sorry, i can't test it so i just guess every time... Edited my answer again, please try it and let me know

Comment: here is live example, with editable code, you can try hrer http://jsfiddle.net/TCpkb/ thanks

Comment: Edited again, going back to CSS. Please switch back to the original version of your form and make the changes above :)

Comment: much more betrer! thank you!
Is there an option that the red or the orange alert box will be thight to the text?

Comment: I'm not sure it's what you mean, but try to replace `padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;` to `padding:2px;` in the _.formError .formErrorContent_ css rule

Comment: here is a picture for what I mean. pleas you are almost thhre! keep help me pleas! https://www.dropbox.com/s/hpqb863dvc6nn6w/%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%93%D7%94%20%282%29.PNG

Comment: I can see what you mean... Sorry but if you remove these parts, everything will lose it's position, and go back as it was before my last edit :(

Comment: so there is no way to fix it?

Comment: Sure there can be a way: calculate the width of each error message, any time it's displayed, and then adjust the left position. I don't really think it's worth the effort ;)

Comment: Try with [jQuery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
            align:left;
```

or

```
            float:left;
```